# Show/hide depending on dropdown menu selection

Tags: javascript

So I have a dropdown menu. The id for this dropdown menu is "courses". This dropdown also has an additional attribute, `onclick="displayField();`

The dropdown has 2 options.

2 and 3.

Now, I want everything with the class `rsform-block-cotecours1` to be hidden depending on which option is chosen.

Here is the JavaScript for that:

```
function displayField()
{
  if(document.getElementById("courses").text == '2';)
  document.getElementsByClassName('rsform-block-cotecours1').style.display="none";

  if(document.getElementById("courses").text == '3';)
  document.getElementsByClassName('rsform-block-cotecours1').style.display="";
}


window.addEvent('domready', function() {
displayField();
});
```

However, this doesn't work, and I don't know why.

Comment: It should be document.getElementById("courses").value

Comment: And also document.getElementsByClassName(..) returns Array hence you should write document.getElementsByClassName('rsform-block-cotecours1')[0].style.display ='none';

Comment: I'm using a plugin that won't allow me to give a value to the dropdowns, so I have to use document.getElementById("courses").text

Comment: see the edit to access text of selected item

Comment: @FelixMaxime did you check fiddle in my answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

**Fiddle:** [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sid_m/Wf3g2/258/)

```
<select id="courses" onchange="ddlChange()">
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
 </select>
```

**JavaScript**

```
function ddlChange() {

    if (document.getElementById("courses").value =="2"){
      document.getElementsByClassName('rsform-block-cotecours1')[0].style.display="none";
        alert(document.getElementById("courses").value );
    }     
     if (document.getElementById("courses").value == "3"){
      document.getElementsByClassName('rsform-block-cotecours1')[0].style.display="block";
         alert(document.getElementById("courses").value );
    }     
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the code to following and test

```
function displayField()
{
  if(document.getElementById("courses").value == '2';)
  document.getElementsByClassName('rsform-block-cotecours1')[0].style.display="none";

  if(document.getElementById("courses").value == '3';)
  document.getElementsByClassName('rsform-block-cotecours1')[0].style.display="";
}


window.addEvent('domready', function() {
displayField();
});
```

in case you want to access the ext and not the value of dropdown list in javascript, then use following code to access the text of selected option from drop down

```
var courseElement = document.getElementById("courses");
var text = "";
if (courseElement.selectedIndex != -1)
{
    text = courseElement.options[courseElement.selectedIndex].text;
}
```

Comment: Does not work. I cannot manipulate the value of the dropdown items, only their text. However I tried both and neither work.

Comment: Have you tried to debug the application. Try to put alert and check where it is failing to work